# ‘I for one’ / „Ich für meinen Teil” en Esperanto

Tags: translation

Mi demandis min kiel oni diras la Anglan ‘I for one’ aŭ la Germanan „Ich für meinen Teil” en Esperanto.

Mi ne povis trovi tiun frazon en ajna vortaro.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- ***Miaflanke*** mi esperas ke jes. I for one hope so. ("on my side")
- ***Miavice*** mi ne balotos por li. I for one will not be voting for him. ("on my turn")
- *Mi **kiel unu spektanto** ne konsentas.* As one observer, I do not agree. ("as one...")

Answer (score 6):

Oni povas uzi "miavice" en tia senco.

Notu, ke preciza signifo de tiaj esprimoj ne estas klare difinebla. Eĉ ne tute klaras al mi, ke "I for one" havas tute la saman signifon kiel "Ich für meinen Teil" (ekzemple en eŭropuniaj tekstoj, laŭ [linguee.de](http://www.linguee.de/deutsch-englisch/uebersetzung/ich+f%C3%BCr+meinen+teil.html) "für meinen Teil" estas kutime respondas al la angla "for my part", kaj praktike neniam al "for one"). Sed ili certe havas tre similan signifon, kaj ankaŭ la signifo de "miavice" similas al ili.